# AjaxControlToolkit AutoCompleteExtender: How to preserve initial text after selection

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

This is my first post, so be gentle :)

I am developing an ASP.NET web user control that will allow a user to type in some **free text** in a multi-line textbox and the application will asynchronously stem the words and use Ajax to submit them to a web service for further processing. The web service processes the words and returns a number of choices (id, title) back to the user.

Naturally, I used the AutoCompleteExtender control which basically covered all my needs but one. **Once a user makes a selection from the popup window, I need to keep track of the selected item, BUT, I do NOT wish for my typed-in text to disappear or be replaced by the item selected by the user** (as what AutoCompleteExtender seems to do by default).

Does this make any sense? I want the "OnClientItemSelected" event to fire (so as to know which item was selected by the user), **BUT**, I don't want to have to "lose" the content typed-in by the user.

Can anyone help?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DelimiterCharacters="&quot; &quot;"` property in your extender mark-up.

Basically, what seems to happen, is that the extender will recognise a new "suggestion" after it sees your specified delimiting character. In this case, " " (a normal space.)

You can also use any other delimiter, I.e ",".